# Cannot select data on linked SQL Server using SQL authentication

Tags: sql-server

I have created a linked server using SQL authentication and the connection seems to work as I can select from the master database.

However, I cannot select from a specific database to which the SQL account I use in the linked server has access.

I tried following the suggestions in other similar posts in here but to no avail. Any help really appreciated. I am attaching a screenshot of the security settings.

[image: Security settings]

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps this is too simplistic, but does the SQL account have a mapping to the other database on the linked server?  What roles is it in there?

Comment: Hi Robert, yes there is an identical account of the linked server that has access to the database. Both are SQL accounts.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a long shot, but since no one else is answering so we'll give it a go.  If you restored the DB from another server, it's possible the ssid's are out of whack.  Switch context to the DB on the linked server and run the following.

```
EXEC sys.sp_change_users_login @Action = 'Report'
```

If any results show up with the login in question, remove it by running this.

```
EXEC  sp_change_users_login @Action='update_one', @UserNamePattern='your_user',@LoginName='your_login';
```

Comment: Hi Robert, that is not the case, the database was not restored. Thanks.